# Remove empty content in array and sorted the array in C

Tags: c

I had face a problem which is I try to remove the content of the array which is zero and sort the array with value. Anyone has any suggestion on how to sorted the array ?

Let's say I got an array:

int array[10] = {1,2,513,0,4,5,6,0,0,9};

which I want convert to
array[10] = {1,2,513,4,5,6,9,0,0,0}

Any function to do that, with the least code require.
I would suspect had a very intelligent way to do that. 
Again, please use the minimum code to handle this. 
Thanks everyone

Comment: Are all the entries non-negative?

Comment: [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)?

Comment: yes, all entries non-negative.

Comment: After edit it is very unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Note that your final array is not sorted. Do you want the equivalent of `std::partition` in C++?

Comment: @Osiris, I only want to remove zero, the content remain same.

Comment: Your comment conflicts with your question which asks for the data to be in ascending order.

Comment: @JackdonChew `and sort the array with value in ascending order`. Then remove this from your question.

Comment: @Osiris Sorry my fault. That make misunderstanding. Removed

Comment: @JackdonChew I have edited my answer, hope it's more usefull now.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Their final array is sorted in ascending lexicographic order on the key that is the ordered pair (element == 0, original index of element).

Comment: Have you considered the use of linked-lists so you can simply move the zero-elements to the tail of the list?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't understand what you say. How an integer array will be sorted by lexicographic order ? Do you want to say that every even index (like array[0], array[2] ...) will act as a index and every odd index (like array[1], array[3] ...) will act as a "data" ? array[0] being the index of array[1], and array[3] being the data of array[2] ?

Comment: Lexicographic order on an ordered pair means to sort primarily by the first element of the pair and to use the second element in case of ties. The first element of the pair, `element == 0` will be zero for non-zero elements and one for zero elements, so it will sort zeros to the end fo the array. The second element of the pair, the original index of the element, will, within those two groups (non-zero elements and zero elements), sort by their original location. So it will preserve their original order.

Comment: I have updated my answer in regard of the bug we encoutered. If someone have an idea on what's going on, I will happily read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, you don't want to sort your array after all ?

Well, this is the code to "remove" all the zero in an array.
Since you changed many time your question, I don't know if it will be the rigth answer.

If you have question, do not hesitate.
The algorithm used below is a commom algorithm : recopy the array with an offset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void Array_Display(const int * const array, const size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void Array_MagicFunction(int * const array, size_t *size)
{
    size_t j = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < *size; ++i) {
        if (array[i] != 0) {
            array[j] = array[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    *size = j;
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int    array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1,2,513,0,4,5,6,0,0,9};
    size_t size              = ARRAY_SIZE;


    Array_Display(array, size);

    Array_MagicFunction(array, &size);

    Array_Display(array, size);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I keep my first answer in case you still want to sort your array.

### ----------

Edit : Attention please.
The provided code below doesn't work for Jackdon for some mysterious reasons.
It seem that his implementation of qsort is bugged (which is really surprising consedering a bug in a massive used function is higlhy improbable) : even when the function return the correct value, the array is not sorted ...

I don't understand what's going on, I'm pretty sure that my code is correct (and it work on Debian9), so I just put some poor "debugging".
Jackdon environment is the following :

- Windows 10
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community
- the compile setting is follow default

---

Tom's To Jackdon :

> Could you please replace the intcmp function with this ?
>
> ```
> int intcmp(const void *first, const void *second)
> {
>     const int *firstInt = first;
>     const int *secondInt = second;
>     int       result;
>
>     if (*firstInt == 0) {
>         result = 1;
>     } else {
>         result = (*firstInt) - (*secondInt);
>     }
>
>     printf("POOR DEBUG : ");
>     for (size_t i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
>         printf("%d ", array[i]);
>     }
>     printf("\ncomparing %d to %d : %d\n", *firstInt, *secondInt, result);
>
>     return (result);
> }
> ```

---

Jackdon To Tom's

> ```
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 1 to 5 : -4
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 1 to 9 : -8
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 5 to 9 : -4
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 2 to 5 : -3
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 3 to 5 : -2
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 5 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 5 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 5 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 0 9
> comparing 6 to 5 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 4 to 5 : -1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 5 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 4 to 5 : -1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 4 to 5 : -1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 6 to 0 : 6
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 6 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 0 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 9 to 0 : 9
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 6 to 0 : 6
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 6 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 0 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 6 to 0 : 6
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 0 to 6 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 6 to 0 : 6
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 2 to 1 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 3 to 2 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 5 to 3 : 2
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 5 4 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 4 to 5 : -1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 2 to 1 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 3 to 2 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 4 to 3 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 2 to 1 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 3 to 2 : 1
> POOR DEBUG : 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> comparing 2 to 1 : 1
> 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 0 0 9
> ```

### ----------

Use qsort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int intcmp(const void *first, const void *second)
{
    const int *firstInt = first;
    const int *secondInt = second;

    if (*firstInt == 0) {
        return (1);
    }
    return (*firstInt - *secondInt);
}

#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int array[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0,0,9};

    qsort(array, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(*array), intcmp);

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The "removing zero" part is handled by putting all zero at the end of the array. So your final array length will simply be found by searching the index of the first zero in the array (don't forget to take care if there is no 0 is the array to begin with).

Comment: I believe the first answer will do. And the second answer: Lets assume the array below : a[10] = 1,2,9,0,0,6,0,0,9,8. After using those function , a[10] = 1,2,9,6,9,8,0,0,9,8. It wont remove the last. Just that your "size" will skip it on display there. Is it my understanding correct ?

Comment: @JackdonChew Yes, it's exactly like that. If you want your array to be "coherent", then just add `for (size_t i = j; i < *size; ++i) { array[i] = 0;}` after the for loop and before modifying "size".

Comment: I tested your first answer with qsort, the output is not correct. The output is 1,2,3,4,5,0,6,0,0,9. But what we expected is 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,0,0,0.

Comment: @JackdonChew I have just tested again the first answer, and it work as intended. Are you sure of what you do ? You don't add or remove other code ? You don't make the qsort after the printing ?

Comment: The answer for me no need to display. I just needed the content inside the array is correct then good enough. Thanks

Comment: I copy exactly fromyour answer. And test it again, the result still same 1,2,3,4,5,0,6,0,0,9.

Comment: @JackdonChew Well, I have no explanation. Maybe an UB. If someone could test my code or see if there is an error, I will apreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179116/discussion-between-jackdon-chew-and-toms).